# I am getting this error "xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python3', requesting installation of command line developer tools." due to python upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, angular, xcode, python-2.7

revclerx@Revclerxs-Mac-mini ~ % python -v
2024-02-19 22:57:28.212 xcodebuild[15788:1110225] [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/DebuggerLLDB, 0x0109): Library not loaded: @rpath/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3
Referenced from:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/usr/lib/swift/host/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/DebuggerLLDB, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/DebuggerLLDB, 0x0109): Library not loaded: @rpath/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3
Referenced from:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/usr/lib/swift/host/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DebuggerLLDB” couldn’t be loaded.}, dyldError = dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/DebuggerLLDB, 0x0000): Library not loaded: @rpath/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3
Referenced from:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/usr/lib/swift/host/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../InternalFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/AppleInternal/Library/Xcode/PrivateFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file)
2024-02-19 22:57:28.212 xcodebuild[15788:1110225] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in IDEFrameworks/IDEFoundation/Initialization/IDEInitialization.m:324
Details:  Xcode failed its initial plug-in scan, error = Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 "Loading a plug-in failed." UserInfo={DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/DebuggerLLDB, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/DebuggerLLDB, 0x0000): Library not loaded: @rpath/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3
Referenced from:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/usr/lib/swift/host/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../InternalFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/AppleInternal/Library/Xcode/PrivateFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in “com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB” at path “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000854480 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/DebuggerLLDB, 0x0109): Library not loaded: @rpath/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3
Referenced from:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/usr/lib/swift/host/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle couldn’t be loaded., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/DebuggerLLDB, NSDebugDescription=dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/DebuggerLLDB, 0x0109): Library not loaded: @rpath/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3
Referenced from:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/LLDB
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/usr/lib/swift/host/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDevice.framework/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Python3' (no such file), NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.framework, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “DebuggerLLDB” couldn’t be loaded.}}}
Function: BOOL _IDEInitializePlugInManager(IDEInitializationOptions, NSError *__autoreleasing  _Nullable * _Nullable)
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x60000128c2c0>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2024-02-19 22:57:28.213 xcodebuild[15788:1110225] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/hr/69f956y529j9hykwh96d3nnr0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2024-19-02_22-57-0028.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: Initialization failed.
Reason: Loading a plug-in failed.
python3: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find python3 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17920: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python3', requesting installation of command line developer tools.

Comment: I installed python version 2.7.10 but still getting this issue